# Group by mean for element with value >0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,0],"y":[1,1,1,1]})
df.groupby("y").agg(x_sum=("x",np.mean))
```

This code gives average of x, the output is 1.5 `((1+2+3+0)/4=1.5)`
but I want average of x where the number of larger than 0, so the output should be `(1+2+3)/3=2`.
How should I address it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace not greater like `0` in `x` column to `NaN`:

```
df.x = df.x.where(df.x.gt(0))
#alternative
#df.x = df.x.mask(df.x.le(0))
print (df)
     x  y
0  1.0  1
1  2.0  1
2  3.0  1
3  NaN  1

df1 = df.groupby("y").agg(x_sum=("x",np.mean))
print (df1)
   x_sum
y       
1    2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write and use your custom function. Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def mean_without_zero_values(values):
    vals = [v for v in values if v > 0]
    return np.mean(vals)

df=pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,0],"y":[1,1,1,1]})
result = df.groupby("y").agg(x_sum=("x",mean_without_zero_values))

print(result)
# output
#    x_sum
# y
# 1      2
```